# Issue with PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' used by 'Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2' matches identity 'Google.Apis.Auth

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, google-bigquery, google-api

I am trying to connect with Google BigQuery and was able to connect and get the data using `Google.Apis.BigQuery.V2` but it seems it has some limits with the size of data that we can pull then i went ahead and tried `Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2` where getting below error, where it states the identity matches. How can i handle this situation?

> Warning at line 67: Assuming assembly reference 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.60.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' used by 'Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2' matches identity 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.64.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' of 'Google.Apis.Auth', you may need to supply runtime policy

I am able to connect with Google BigQuery using `Google.Apis.BigQuery.V2` but when i tried connecting with `Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2` i am getting the above error. Stating 'Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2' matches identity 'Google.Apis.Auth,